# Multiple conditions in a function using PSR

Tags: php, coding-standards

I'm trying use the PSR conventions in all my projects, but today I view some code of my co-worker and I disagree.

```
if ($cond == 1 AND $cond == 2) {
    // to-do
}
```

For me, the correct is:

```
if (($cond == 1) AND ($cond == 2)) {
    // to-do
}
```

**What is the correct use of the PSR?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the PHP Framework Interop Group's PSR definitions, this particular case is not addressed:

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

I don't see any guidance on the usage of logical operators as "words", i.e. "and", "or", "not", etc versus symbols, i.e. "&&", "||", "!" within boolean expressions.

If I were to follow precedence and make my own extension of the above PSR reference, I could only conclude that the word "AND" should be written as "and" given the preference for lower case when using reserved words...

Comment: Both of the examples given use AND (which I also think should be lowercased for PSR2); the difference between them is the redundant parentheses. AFAICT that's not a violation of PSR2 either, but I would say it's still bad coding style. If you go the route that PSR2 letting you have one pair of redundant parentheses means it's a good idea, why not have two pairs or ten? Just because PSR2 lets you doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: @mmitchell good catch and logical position on my answer.